# proof of combinatoric/using pascals theorem

Tags: combinatorics

prove that, for even values of $n$, $$\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i}= 2^{n-1}\;.$$
I tried using pascals theorem to help prove this with no success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to prove that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i}=2^{n-1}\tag{1}$$

when $n$ is even. The easiest way is with a combinatorial argument. The lefthand side of $(1)$ counts the subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ of even cardinality. Exactly half of the subsets of any finite, non-empty set have even cardinality, and $\{1,\dots,n\}$ has $2^n$ subsets altogether, so ... ?

**Added:** You **can** use Pascal’s identity to prove it, though.

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i}&=\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}\left(\binom{n-1}{2i-1}+\binom{n-1}{2i}\right)\tag{2}\\\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}i\\\\
&=2^{n-1}\;.
\end{align*}$$

The terms on the righthand side of $(2)$ actually range from $\binom{n-1}{-1}$ through $\binom{n-1}n$, but the two extra terms, $\binom{n-1}{-1}$ and $\binom{n-1}n$, are both $0$, so I simply dropped them in the single summation in the next line.

Comment: Thanks that cleared things up!

Comment: @Scott: Glad to hear it; you’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
E:=\sum_{0\le i\le n,\ \  i \text{  even}} \binom{n}{i},\ \ \ \ \ 
O:=\sum_{0\le i\le n,\ \  i \text{  odd}} \binom{n}{i}.
$$
By the binomial theorem, 
$$
E+O=\sum_{0\le i\le n} \binom{n}{i}=(1+1)^n=2^n$$
and, if $n\ge 1$,
$$
E-O=\sum_{0\le i\le n} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i}=(1-1)^n=0.$$
Therefore, $E=O=2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternating Sum**

If we take the alternating sum of any row other than the top row we get something like the following:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

Each number in gray contributes to one number in the lower row which is positive in the sum (green +) and one that is negative (red -) in the sum. Thus, the alternating sum adds and subtracts each of the gray numbers, giving a total of $0$.

**Non-Alternating Sum**

Each number in gray contributes to two numbers in the lower row. Thus the sum of the lower row is twice that of the upper row.

**Putting It Together**

From the arguments above, we see that for all but the top row,
$$
\sum_i\binom{n}{2i}-\sum_i\binom{n}{2i+1}=0\tag{1}
$$
and since the sum of the $n=0$ row is $1$, we get
$$
\sum_i\binom{n}{2i}+\sum_i\binom{n}{2i+1}=2^n\tag{2}
$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ and dividing by $2$ yields
$$
\sum_i\binom{n}{2i}=2^{n-1}\tag{3}
$$